# Delimit multiple Columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

How to delimit multiple columns using macros when the data in each column is separated by an underscore (_). Preferable, this would be an automated process.

Comment: Text to Columns?  It's on the data tab.

Comment: Text To Columns with a custom delimiter will do this. Is there a specific reason it needs to be VBA?
If so, please provide us with a code sample - SO is not a coding service. Where are you stuck at?

Comment: For VBA: Use Split(input, "_") to create an array of values, then loop through the array and place values in the respective columns

Comment: I'm aware that text to columns is an option. I want to do it with macros. I will provide sample code in my next post. It would need to be in VBA because of the amount of data that I am working with

Comment: Here is where I am, but obviously i've made a mistake somewhere                 Sub Delimit(P2)
Dim objRange1 As Range

    'Set up the ranges
    Set objRange1 = Range("P2:P78")

    'Do the first parse
    objRange1.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("P2:P78")
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:=" _"
      
End Sub